# Mysql 8 CASE..WHEN..THEN..END throws syntax error

Tags: mysql-8.0

I have this query which works without problems in Mysql 5.* but I recently upgraded to MySQL 8 and now the query throws a syntax error as follows:

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'row_number, @breed'*

The query is (lots of useless detail removed for simplicity):

```
SELECT `name`, `age`, breed
                FROM (
                    SELECT
                        `dogs`.`name`,
                        `dogs`.`age`,
                         @row_number:=CASE WHEN @breed=breed
                                     THEN @row_number+1
                                     ELSE 1
                                END AS row_number
                     , @breed:=breed AS breed
                FROM `dogs` /* other details with joins, subqueries and limits left out for simplicity*/;
```

`breed` is supposed to maintain a row count so I can get n rows for rows grouped by `breed`. That is, if n=2, for example, my result would be:

```
name | age | breed
------------------
fifi | 2 | labrador
bingo | 5 | labrador
rocket | 1 | german shepherd
sky | 1 german shepherd
```

My main question is why I get the syntax error. Google, is my friend, but not in this case... I tried. I also tried removing "as", adding brackets around the case/when/then/end but no joy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain that MySQL 8 supports user variables in the same way as MySQL 5.x does.  In any case, your current syntax is at least deprecated, and you should just be using the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function.  For example, assuming you wanted the two youngest animals per breed, you could try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY breed ORDER BY age) rn
    FROM dogs
    -- maybe joins here
)

SELECT name, age, breed
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2;
```